What is the optimal method to resuspend competent cells during wash steps?
I've recently moved on to making my own competent cells instead of buying commercially. I'm currently making electrocompetent cells. I was taught to swirl the pellets (in 500 mL conical tubes) in the ice buckets to resuspend, but they don't seem to resuspend very well. How important is the exact method of resuspension? Would a serological pipette resuspension be too harsh? I know vortexing would be an no-go, so I'm stuck between those two methods.
Thanks!

Electrocompetent cells are a bit more finicky than chemically competent in this respect.
Generally you do need to be gentle during the preparation - swirling is fine, but vortexing is not. Too vigorous a resuspension results in foaming of the medium and damage to the cells, which results in lower competency. However, in my experience, resuspension with a pipette is fine, so long as you don't cause a lot of bubbling in the solution. For small volumes a Pasteur pipette with a rubber bulb works well for this, or a pipettor set on about 50% for bigger volumes.
How much competency you lose by being too vigorous is up for debate, but in my experience you might lose about a log10 by being too rough. For competencies over about 107, I don't find that this is too big an issue, but it does depend on what you are trying to do (e.g. BAC vs plasmid) and the size of the DNA you are trying to add. The larger the DNA, the harder it is to transform the bacteria and the higher you need your competency to be.

I am trying to transform 30-50 kb constructs from yeast into E. coli. Yeast minipreps are notoriously low-yielding (low copy number construct), so I do need particularly high competency to overcome the limitations of the yeast minipreps. Thank you for your insights.

@OmarAntonioOcegueda check the protocols at Openwetware under Escherichia coli, particularly the Knight lab ones. Also have a look at Current Protocols in Molecular Biology - they usually have a section on considerations and background that is quite helpful in understanding the critical steps.

Thank you for the protoccol resources. I appreciate it. I haven't heard of openwetware before. I just found recipes for the Qiagen buffers which is neat lol
